# mobie optimized layout is it correct?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a mobile-optimized layout with CSS and HTLM5.

I have added this code at the bottom of my styles

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
        padding: 5px;
        background-color:#FFF;
        background-image:url(images/smoothieworld_logo_mobile.jpg;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
    #wrap {
    with:auto;
    margin-top:80px;
   }
   #masthead, sidebar {
    display:none;
   }
   #mainnav {
    height: auto;
   }
   #mainnav li {
    float:none;
    width: auto;
    text-align:left;
    border-top: 1px grey solid;
    border-bottom: 1px grey solid;
   }
   #maincontent {
    float: none;
    width:auto;
    background-color:white;
   }
   #footer, #footer p {
    clear:none;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    background-image:none;
    padding-top:20px;
    margin-top:0px;
   }
   }
```

This doesn't work when I preview in my browsers Safari and Firefox both up to date.

I then added a script underneath links to my styles as so

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="reset.css" type="text/css"  />
   <link  rel="stylesheet" media="screen"  href="base.css" type="text/css"  />
   <script scr="modernizer-2.6.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It doesn't preview correctly when I reduce the width of my browsers.

What have I done wrong? Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your head.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`